# How to get the selected Radiobutton in multi-lingual Android app?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

In my Android app I've got a group of radiobuttons with a couple values. I'm also building an API to which I need to send the selected value. I can of course get the text of the selected radio button with something like:

```
RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.myradiogroup);
String selectedValue = ((RadioButton) getView().findViewById(myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

The problem is that the app will be translated to a couple different languages, which makes the value change as well. The thing remaining constant however, is the id of the different buttons. For this reason I thought of simply getting the id of the selected button and use that to talk to the API. The thing is that I can only get the radioButtonId as an int of which I don't even know if it is constant. Plus, it doesn't make for easy code reading.

So my question; does anybody know how I can get the id of a radiobutton as a string?

Comment: Can't you just use something as simple as?


String radioBtnId = ""+getView().findViewById(R.id.myradiogroup);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the id of the button: `myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`

The radio button group is a set of views, is returning to you the Id of the button that is currently selected in the group (which is an int like you posted).

That Id will always be the same no matter what language settings, etc, so now all you have to do is determine what to do based on the id. You have the ids of the individual buttons (either when you create them or via R) so you should be good.  The exact solution really depends on how you are inflating that RadioGroup.

```
int selectedButtonId = myRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
if (selectedButtonId == R.id.button1)  //or the saved Id when you created the view
{
    //do something...
}
else if (selectedButtonId == R.id.button2) //or the saved Id when you created the view
{
    //do something else...
}
```

Comment: The result of this is something like 2131230855. How can I know from that if it is option 1, 2 or 3 that is being selected by the user? I want something that is constant across languages (which getText() is not), and which I can send to the API (so something like "option_1"). Since the id name is the only thing that is constant accross languages, I thought of using that.